# No carga los valores correctos en C

Tags: c

Buen día, mi subprograma no carga correctamente los valores, al momento de imprimir el los sueldos de cada turno, en el sueldo de dia me da el valor del sueldo de tarde, y en el sueldo de tarde no aparece nada.

Ya intente declarando las variables dentro de cada función pero asi simplemente no compila.

```
#include<stdio.h>  

void sueldodia(){  
float dia[4], sueldo;  
printf("\n¿Cuanto ganan en el turno de dia?: ");  
scanf("%f",&sueldo);  
for (int n=0;n<4;n++){  
    dia[n]=sueldo;  
}
}

void sueldotarde(){  
float tarde[4], sueldos;  
printf("\n¿Cuanto ganan en el turno de tarde?: ");  
scanf("%f",&sueldos);  
for (int n=0;n<4;n++){  
    tarde[n]=sueldos;  
}  
}  

float gastosturnodia(){  
float dia[4], total=0;  
for(int n=0;n<4;n++){  
    total+=dia[n];  
}  
return total;  
}  



float gastosturnotarde(){  
float tarde[4], total2=0;  
for(int n=0;n<4;n++){  
    total2+=tarde[n];  
}  
return total2;  
}  

void main(){  
float dia[4], tarde[4];  

sueldodia();  
sueldotarde();  
printf("\nEl gasto del turno de dia es: %.2f",gastosturnodia(dia[4]));  
printf("\nEl gasto del turno de tarde es: %.2f",gastosturnotarde(tarde[4]));  
}
```

Comment: Dato importante: la variable `dia` en el main no es la misma variable `dia` de sueldodia y gastosturnodia, de forma similar para la variable `tarde`. Te recomiendo revisar sobre el alcance o ámbitos de las variables (scope), por ejemplo revisa https://codingornot.com/ambito-o-scope-en-programacion

Answer (score 9):

Mencionaré las fallas que tiene tu programa:

**1.** En esta línea de código dará un posible error de compilación, debido a que las funciones `gastosturnodia` y `gastosturnotarde`fueron definidos con un solo parámetro, es decir, al momento de llamar dicha función, no puedes pasar ningún argumento.

```
printf("\nEl gasto del turno de dia es: %.2f",gastosturnodia(dia[4])); 
printf("\nEl gasto del turno de tarde es: %.2f",gastosturnotarde(tarde[4]));
```

**2.** La forma como estás pasando el argumento al parámetro es incorrecto.

```
gastosturnodia(dia[4])
gastosturnotarde(tarde[4])
```

Lo que estarías pasando al parámetro de `gastosturnodia` es una dirección de memoria que no le pertenece al arreglo de caracteres `dia` (así mismo pasaría con `tarde`). Por lo tanto, a esto se lo conoce [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer), como el tamaño máximo es `4`, solo es válido usar índices de `0` a `3`, si escribes el `4` en el operador de corchetes (`[]`), desbordas el arreglo y esto puede ocasionar sobreescritura en alguna área de memoria de tu propio programa y lograr que sea difícil de depurar (porqué no sabes en que punto del programa sucede el desbordamiento).

**¡Así que mucho cuidado!**

**3.** El resultado por pantalla **NUNCA** mostrará los gastos del turno de día o de noche, porqué al momento de terminar la ejecución de ambas funciones: `sueldodia` y `sueldotarde` se perderá la información que se haya pedido al usuario, ya que cada variable local, parámetro de una función se liberará de la memoria (es decir, esos espacios de memoria ya no le pertenecen al programa, porqué fueron liberados) al momento de finalizar su ejecución.

De este modo, es imposible que las funciones `gastosturnotarde` y `gastosturnodia` logren hacer la suma total de los gastos de turno por día o de noche, debido a que, no tienen acceso a la información que se haya pedido en las funciones: `sueldodia` o `sueldotarde`.

**4.** La forma como pides el sueldo no es la forma correcta, debido a que, solo estarías pidiendo únicamente un sueldo y debería ser varios, por lo tanto, estas dos líneas de códigos necesitan estar adentro del bucle for:

```
printf("\n¿Cuanto ganan en el turno de dia?: ");  
scanf("%f",&sueldo);  
//Lo mismo hay que aplicar en la función sueldotarde
```

**Solución:**

Para que la información de gastos se presenten al usuario, deberás agregar en cada función un parámetro (de tipo [puntero](http://lsi.vc.ehu.es/pablogn/docencia/manuales/C/Punteros%20en%20C.html)) en la cual recibirá la dirección base (del primer elemento) del arreglo `dia` o `noche` de la función `main`.

Con los cambios que mencioné anteriormente, el código quedaría de esta manera:

```
void sueldodia(float* dia)
{  
    float sueldo;  
    for (int n=0;n<4;n++)
    {  
        printf("\n¿Cuanto ganan en el turno de dia?: ");  
        scanf("%f",&sueldo);  
        dia[n]=sueldo;  
    }
}

void sueldotarde(float* tarde)
{  
    float sueldos;  
    for (int n=0;n<4;n++)
    {  
        printf("\n¿Cuanto ganan en el turno de tarde?: ");  
        scanf("%f",&sueldos);  
        tarde[n]=sueldos;  
    }  
}  

float gastosturnodia(float* dia)
{  
    float total=0;  
    for(int n=0;n<4;n++)
        total+=dia[n];    
    return total;  
}  


float gastosturnotarde(float* tarde)
{  
    float total2=0;  
    for(int n=0;n<4;n++)
        total2+=tarde[n];   
    return total2;  
}  

int main()
{  
    float dia[4], tarde[4];  

    sueldodia(dia);  
    sueldotarde(tarde);  
    printf("\nEl gasto del turno de dia es: %.2f",gastosturnodia(dia));  
    printf("\nEl gasto del turno de tarde es: %.2f",gastosturnotarde(tarde));  
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** Me di cuenta que el código está redundante. Es decir, las funciones `sueldodia` y `sueldotarde` tienen el mismo código, por lo tanto, podríamos dejar una función para evitar redundancia.

La nueva función se llamaría `pedirSueldo` (básicamente es el reemplazo de `sueldodia` y `sueldotarde`). Adicionalmente tiene un parámetro extra donde se puede especificar en la función si se quiere pedir el sueldo por día o de noche.

```
void pedirSueldo(float* dn, const char* type)
{  
    float sueldo;  
    for (int n=0;n<4;n++)
    {  
        printf("\n¿Cuanto ganan en el turno de %s?: ", type);  
        scanf("%f",&sueldo);  
        dn[n]=sueldo;  
    }
}
```

Las funciones `gastosturnodia`, `gastosturnotarde` también están redundantes, por esa razón nos podríamos quedar únicamente con una función, ya sea `gastosturnodia` o `gastosturnotarde`

Con los cambios mencionado, el nuevo programa quedaría de esta manera:

```
void pedirSueldo(float* dn, const char* type)
{  
    float sueldo;  
    for (int n=0;n<4;n++)
    {  
        printf("\n¿Cuanto ganan en el turno de %s?: ", type);  
        scanf("%f",&sueldo);  
        dn[n]=sueldo;  
    }
}

float gastosTurno(float* dn)
{  
    float total=0;  
    for(int n=0;n<4;n++)
        total+=dn[n];    
    return total;  
}  


int main()
{  
    float dia[4];
    float noche[4];
    pedirSueldo(dia, "dia");
    pedirSueldo(noche, "noche");

    printf("\nEl gasto del turno de dia es: %.2f",gastosTurno(dia));  
    printf("\nEl gasto del turno de tarde es: %.2f",gastosTurno(noche));  
    return 0;
}
```

Si te das cuenta en estas dos líneas:

```
pedirSueldo(dia, "dia");
pedirSueldo(noche, "noche");
```

Los argumentos que estamos pasando tienen el mismo nombre. Entonces, ¿como podríamos pasar únicamente un argumento sin pasar el otro? Usando [macros](https://www.programacion.com.py/escritorio/c/defines-y-macros-en-c).

```
#define P_SUELDO(arr) pedirSueldo(arr, #arr)
```

De este modo nos ahorramos en escribir menos caracteres con el [operador Stringizing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/and-operators-in-c/) (`#`), lo que hace es convertir el argumento que se le pase a `arr` en cadena, es decir, si el argumento fuera `dia`, el operador lo convierte a `"dia"`.

Por último, para usar la macro lo hacemos de esta manera:

```
P_SUELDO(dia);
P_SUELDO(noche);
```

Básicamente el código de arriba el [pre-procesador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocesador_de_C) lo expande a:

```
pedirSueldo(dia, "dia");
pedirSueldo(noche, "noche");
```

Comment: Cuidado con la macro `P_SUELDO`, no garantiza que el segundo argumento sea valido si haces algo como `P_SUELDO(arr + 4)`.